# Laravel Eloquent where value is email has correct syntax

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using Laravel's Eloquent to build queries.

Now, I have a tabel with one column "email" and I would like to select all rows that have an email address with valid syntax in this column. I am aware of the validator but can't find out to combine this with Eloquent.

Does someone have help?

Comment: How would you decide if it was a valid email in the real world? Because it contains an `@` character? Because it looks like an email address? Because you've sent an email to that address and got a response?

Comment: you can add validation in your model.

Comment: @MarkBaker I mean the syntax. I corrected my question.

Comment: @MarkBaker `'%@%.%'` should be enough according to the RFCs. If he's dealing with local email addresses then `'%@%'` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by preventing storage of invalid email addresses you would end with less headaches. One idea is if you take all let's say a `users` collection and then run a collection filter for their email:

```
$filteredUsers = $users->filter(function($user)
{
    return filter_var($user->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
});
```

Comment: That can be very expensive in terms of performance. One solution would be to define what's an "acceptable" email address and then do a `where` clause, `Model::where('email', 'LIKE', '%@%.%')`.

Comment: Yes performance will be stressed for sure but the LIKE selection isn't that harmless. Anyway I think the common policy to store only valid email addresses is the best solution.

Comment: I agree that the table should not contatin emails with wrong syntax but in my case it does unfortunally. For now @Ben's answere worked for me even if it is not the best way.